# codeigniter upload file redirects to unknown link

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

this is my controller

```
public function upload_file(){

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    // set path to store uploaded files
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    // set allowed file types
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    // set upload limit, set 0 for no limit
    //$config['max_size']    = 0;
    // load upload library with custom config settings
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload()){
        $this->add_view();
    }else{
        print_r('x');
        exit();
    }
}
```

and my view is

`echo form_open_multipart('PDFuploads/upload');`

the problem is i don't know why it redirected into this  link

`http://localhost/TLC_HR/PDFuploads/upload`

Comment: what your desired result?

Comment: do you have right path with uploads folder

Comment: Why should not it redirect you that link?What is your expected link.

Answer (score 0):

Give the correct controller and action here

```
echo form_open_multipart('controller/action');
```

and you mentioned your controller action as **upload_file()**

Comment: but it still doesnt do $this->upload->do_upload(); why is it?

Comment: Do you have redirection problem or other problem ?

Answer (score 0):

$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')

**userfile**  is missing. input type = "file" name = "userfile"

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'base_url' in application/config/config.php